# asp.net mvc 2 DataAnnotations validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

I have just tried new version of framework (asp.net mvc 2 preview 2) that includes server and client validation with jQuery integrated, looks fine.

it has attributes for properties in my model (entity) like DataType.
where i expand to see which options i have so it has all what u want u dont, like **Duration** and **PhoneNumber** :)

but i dont have simple DataType like **Number**!

regEx does not a good idea for it, cuz i want to user built-in option of **jQuery** validator for number

Answer (score 1):

Range validators will enforce numbers. At least, it works that way with xVal's integration with DataAnnotations and jQuery.validate. I don't know if this works the same way in MVC 2, but it's worth a try.

```
[Range(0, Int32.MaxValue)]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using an integer property:

```
public int Number { get; set; }
```

This will ensure that only numbers can be stored.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you will very seldom want to have any number (as in 0 to 2147483647 for a int). Specifying a range is most of the time a very good idea.

As for phone numbers, create your own attribute validating the phone number. Simply create a class and inherit `ValidationAttribute`